# Power Automate Send Email via SP HTTPS not sending to specific addresses

Tags: http, email, sharepoint, power-automate

I have setup a HTTPS request to SharePoint action in PowerAutomate, Using the Uri _api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail

In the Body, I have 'To': ['myemail@email.com','friendemail@email.com'], along with the rest

In this case the request works and we both receive the email.

However if this changes to ['myemail@email.com','anotherfriendsemail@email.com'] then I receive the email both the other friend does not nor are they listed in the emails To field.

myself and my friend are both owners of the SharePoint site and all parties are part of the same business. The other friend is not a member of the SP site though I tried adding them as an member and then owner and neither worked.

Why does this send to just myself and my friend but not to the other address?

The Error mesage is:

```
{  "status": 400,  "message": "{\"odata.error\":{\"code\":\"-2130242040,Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient.\"}}}\r\nclientRequestId: RecipientID\r\nserviceRequestId: RequestID",  "source": "https://hwinc.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail",  "errors": []}
```

Edit: Full Body Below

```html
Method: Post
Uri: _api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail
Headers: accept   application/json;odata=nometadata
         content-type   application/json;odata=nometadatae
         
Body: {
'properties':{
'From': 'Sharpoint_Site_Name@hwinc.onmicrosoft.com',
'To': ['FirstName.LastName@company.com.au','ABC_Sector@company.com.au'],
'Body': '<p>The Following Order has been Approved:<br><br></p>
<table>
<tr> <td>Approver:</td> <td>@{outputs('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['body/responder/displayName']}</td> </tr>
<tr><td>Date of Order:</td><td>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rfe2e26ab18544ebea75d9b17a5d84af1']}</td></tr>
<tr> <td>Company:</td> <td>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rcd9f1c32a2364690ae6d6dbbb049a306']}</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Customer Name:</td> <td>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r8a29c2d61ac54342a77d1604bd9f796e']}</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Address:</td> <td>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r343a56a5c4ac4f55b11e37c5c3a3f0d4']}</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Estimated Qty:</td> <td>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r8a28c14eddca4884833443357035c7eb']}</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Required Mix:</td> <td>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r2b9c2f804efe49509436a2c44afe4a83']}</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Boral Plant Name:</td> <td>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rcc43d77ecc6f4083ac6d3fbf59ffee75']}</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Plant Code</td> <td>@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r4fd7f3aceb164a67baece47df43933ee']}</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>3rd Party Supplier:</td> <td>@{variables('3rd Party')}</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Price:</td>  <td>@{outputs('Format_Final_Price')?['body']}</td> </tr>
</table>
<p>Kind regards</p>
@{outputs('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['body/responder/displayName']}',
'Subject': 'Urgent! 3rd Party Purchase Order Request'
}
}
```

Comment: Does `anotherfriendsemail` contain any non-alphanumeric characters? Perhaps something which has to be escaped?

Comment: One of the emails i tested does have an underscore, my_friend@email.com when this is included it always fails. Otherwise the standard is firstname.lastname1@email.com where the 1 is only if there are 2 people by the same name. In my test cases there have been no numbers

Comment: To clarify - can you please post full content of `Body` and confirm that all the addresses [belong to your organization](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/246355)?

Comment: All emails do belong to my organisation. On a side note, from that post it seems weird why it can't send emails to recipients outside the org, doesn't pass the pub test you know. Also Thanks for your interest and time Robert

Comment: There are other connectors for sending emails to anyone. Unless there's an important reason to use SharePoint connector, I'd suggest to try the other ones

Comment: Bit of a stumper eh. Yeah, I need it from a No Reply address unfortunately

Comment: There are [many ways to create noreply address in M365](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/no-reply-mailbox-in-microsoft-365/)